# Putting SQL query in CrudRepository to limit columns (and further SQL queries after this)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on a Spring Application which logs User Request response (sends it to DB and retrieves it). 
Fetch records code is like this (Controller):

```
/**
     * this method fetches all userrequest response records from user_request_response table
     * @return
     */
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<UserRequestResponse> getAllRequestResponseRecords() {
        return userRequestResponseRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Dao code:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserProjection;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserRequestResponse;

public interface UserRequestResponseRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRequestResponse, Integer> {


public static final String FIND_QUERY = 
            "select new com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserRequestResponse(user.u_httpstatus ,user.u_queryparam) from UserRequestResponse user";
    @Query(value = FIND_QUERY)
    List<UserProjection> getAllRequestResponseRecords();

}
```

Class with getters and setters: (Removed some variables and their getters and setters)

```
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class UserRequestResponse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private String u_httpstatus;

    private String u_error_message;

    private String u_queryparam;


public UserRequestResponse(String u_httpstatus, String u_queryparam) {
        this.u_httpstatus = u_httpstatus;
        this.u_queryparam = u_queryparam;
    }
    public int getSys_id() {
        return sys_id;
    }
public String getU_httpstatus() {
            return u_httpstatus;
        }

        public void setU_httpstatus(String u_httpstatus) {
            this.u_httpstatus = u_httpstatus;
        }

        public String getU_error_message() {
            return u_error_message;
        }

        public void setU_error_message(String u_error_message) {
            this.u_error_message = u_error_message;
        }

        public String getU_queryparam() {
            return u_queryparam;
        }

        public void setU_queryparam(String u_queryparam) {
            this.u_queryparam = u_queryparam;
        }



    }
```

Projection to extract u_queryparam and u_httpstatus:

```
public interface UserProjection {
    String getU_httpstatus();
    String getU_queryparam();

}
```

MySQL query sample (the query I'm trying to fit in the java code in the CrudRepository, InternSearchAnalytics.user_request_response is the name of the table):

```
select u_httpstatus, u_queryparam from InternSearchAnalytics.user_request_response
```

But, I'm getting all the fields when I run the java code and hit the endpoint produced. Can someone help me out here please. I've been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Comment: Your line :userRequestResponseRepository.findAll()
will call the default findAll from the repository, and not your query.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're getting the full UserProjection entity with all its fields every time you retrieve records?

Comment: Yes. That's true. I'm getting all the fields from the database. Also, I made the projection (interface) because I read it somewhere that it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get selected fields from query using a new constructor in your `UserRequestResponse` class like

```
public UserRequestResponse(String u_httpstatus, String u_queryparam) {
    this.u_httpstatus = u_httpstatus;
    this.u_queryparam = u_queryparam;
}
```

And for the query you should change it using the constructor

```
public static final String FIND_QUERY = 
                    "select new com.your.package.name.UserRequestResponse(user.u_httpstatus ,user.u_queryparam) from UserRequestResponse user";
```

One point is you need to use the constructor with fully qualified name. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol. I've put the constructor as you said and changed the query string. Can you tell me what I've done wrong. I'm editing the question with your suggested editd.

Comment: @ABHINAVSOOD can you share complete stack trace?

Comment: nvm, I solved the error. Thanks a lot. Although I was only successful in getting the required fields and not custom SQL queries like counting based on grouping, etc. I'll put that part in another question with the updated code. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also, can you follow this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215972/custom-sql-queries-in-crudrepository. Thanks a lot.